# Simple Java multihreading test not working

Tags: java, multithreading

I wrote some java code that would increase a value as much it could in 1 second using a while loop.

I then tried increasing four values as much as it could in 1 second using 4 threads. I was expecting that with four threads I would get to four times the value as compared with the simple loop.

Code is as follows:

```
package threadTest;

public class ThreadTestMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    long end_time = 0;
    long value = 0;
    long runtime = 0;

    long start_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while (runtime<=1000) {
        value++;
        runtime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start_time;
    }

    System.out.println(value);
    end_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("DEBUG-> Time should be 1sec : " + (end_time - start_time));

    SeperateExecution myObject = new SeperateExecution(0);
    SeperateExecution myObject2 = new SeperateExecution(0);
    SeperateExecution myObject3 = new SeperateExecution(0);
    SeperateExecution myObject4 = new SeperateExecution(0);

    Thread worker1 = new Thread(myObject,"worker1");
    Thread worker2 = new Thread(myObject2,"worker2");
    Thread worker3 = new Thread(myObject3,"worker3");
    Thread worker4 = new Thread(myObject4,"worker4");

    worker1.start();worker2.start();worker3.start();worker4.start();
}

}
```

and

```
package threadTest;

//import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

public class SeperateExecution implements Runnable {
private long value = 0;
//private AtomicLong value = null;
private long start_time = 0;

public SeperateExecution (long p_val)
{
    this.value = p_val;
    //this.value = new AtomicLong(p_val);
    //this.start_time = p_st;
}

@Override
public void run(){
    long runtime = 0;
    this.start_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while (runtime<=1000) {
        //value.incrementAndGet();
        value++;
        runtime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start_time;
    }
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " DONE " + value + 
            " Thread Exection Time " + (System.currentTimeMillis()- start_time));
}
}
```

The code output is as follows:

```
52266551
DEBUG-> Time should be 1sec : 1001
worker1 DONE 13364059 Thread Exection Time 1001
worker2 DONE 13744972 Thread Exection Time 1001
worker4 DONE 11652084 Thread Exection Time 1001
worker3 DONE 13605645 Thread Exection Time 1001
```

Can someone please help me understand why the multithreaded values sum up to a value less that the normal while loop?

An analogy to help understand my question: If one worker can dig one hole in a day then surly four workers can dig four holes in a day.

Thanks

Comment: The code does not test the performance of increments. It tests the performance of `System.currentTimeMillis()`, and it's not surprising that this method does not scale so well.

Comment: @nosid, I don't know the JVM, but the implementation of System.currentTimeMillis() may be very cheap.  However, look at when the example starts the timers:  It starts them _before the threads are created_.  In fact, the first timer is started before all of the SeparateExecution objects have been created.  So, the threaded case

Comment: Silly question, but how many CPU cores do you have?  If this code is running on a single core, that's exactly the result you'd expect.

Comment: @SamDufel I am running of a dual core i7 which I believe should have 4 threads. Intel Core i7 M620 2.67Ghz Processor.

Comment: @nosid The use of System.currentTimeMillis() is in both threaded and non-threaded code, thus it should affect both methods to the same/similar degree?

Comment: Which os and jvm? Important differences (well not really I don't think the milliseconds implementation in hotspot has changes since 1.5 but haven't checked the logs). Looks like it is synchronized which didn't make much sense at least in Linux - gettimeofday should be thread safe..

Comment: @Voo Im using Java 1.7 Update 51, on a Windows 7 environment. This is basically the first test that came to mind when I decided to test multi-threading. Maybe its not the most ideal to prove the concept, but I would like to understand why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the reason for your result seems rather obvious: `System.currentTimeMillis` acquires a lock somewhere along the way which makes the code basically sequential (the kernel call is by far the most expensive thing that's done in the loop).

In this case you'd expect the numbers of the four threads to be about the same as the sequential version which is pretty much what happens.

The interesting question is why does `System.currentTimeMillis` need a lock? It's a native function that's implemented in `src/os/<os>/vm/os_<os>.cpp` where `<os>` is linux, windows or solaris. The function slightly simplified looks as follows in the jdk9 dev tree:

```
jlong os::javaTimeMillis() {
    FILETIME wt;
    GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(&wt);
    return windows_to_java_time(wt);
}
```

So Java itself does not synchronize since `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime` is thread-safe. So we can assume that the OS internally acquires a lock for that method - rather surprising, I don't really see why that'd be necessary.. the used struct has only 8 byte so could be updated atomically.

Anyhow that's how it is, I wouldn't be surprised if running the same code on Linux wouldn't exhibit such behavior.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it is impossible to get the same number in all threads.

1. You may have 4 procesor , but it is not necessary all four dedicated to your java program . It may swapping the cycle space to other process ( like OS process , other process running .. )
2. I cleaned your code with simple loop without System.currentMill

Here is the result

```
Thread3 Value :413907923
Thread1 Value :431271274
Thread2 Value :426025618
Thread4 Value :431386076
```

I tried with  8 threads ( i have 4 core) here is the results

```
Thread7 Value :441240435
Thread4 Value :283265150
Thread2 Value :427759029
Thread3 Value :441240435
Thread8 Value :283265150
Thread6 Value :427759029
Thread5 Value :450884067
Thread1 Value :450884067
```

(It is not even doing SOP in order)

```
public class SimpleTask implements Runnable {
    private long value = 0;
    private volatile static int oneSecondCompleted = 0;

    public SimpleTask(long lValue) {
        this.value = lValue;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(oneSecondCompleted <= 1){
            if (oneSecondCompleted == 1){
                while (oneSecondCompleted == 1){
                    this.value++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() +" Value :"+value);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){

        SimpleTask task1 = new SimpleTask(0);
        SimpleTask task2 = new SimpleTask(0);
        SimpleTask task3 = new SimpleTask(0);
        SimpleTask task4 = new SimpleTask(0);

        Thread thread1 = new Thread(task1,"Thread1");
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(task2,"Thread2");
        Thread thread3 = new Thread(task3,"Thread3");
        Thread thread4 = new Thread(task4,"Thread4");

        thread1.start();thread2.start();thread3.start();thread4.start();

        oneSecondCompleted = 1;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        oneSecondCompleted = 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: I initially tried one object of SeperateExecution, however the "race" condition is easily noticed when the single thread loop counts to 51663040 and the multithreaded loop increases the one value to only 29446765. Using the AtomicLong has no/minimal effect in my tests.

Comment: And after all this work you have a different program and all no idea what causes the strange behavior in the first place.. What exactly is the point? The interesting question is which platform first of all.

Comment: @QuickPrototype - There are lot of factors involved to increase / decrease the speed. if you run the same code 10 times ( in single thread) each time you might get different numbers . Now a days jvm can optimize your code ( change at runtime) based on successor results and increase your performance.

Comment: @QuickPrototype I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. If you except same number should appear in all threads then it is not nearly possible to achieve unless you force to run n number of times in all threads. Remember it also deponds on the system load / thread creation time / thread availability

Comment: @Mani You're missing the point. The question is why a presumably non-synchronized function would cause this behavior. Windows uses `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime` (check in `src/os/windows/os_windows.cpp` for `os::javaTimeMillis`). The only explanation is that that function internally needs a lock - which I guess makes some sense.

Comment: @Mani I am trying to realize the benefits of multithreading. If i can get 10 computations with one thread in one second then surely I should be able to get four threads to each do 10 computations in 1 second thus having a combined value of 40 computations done in the one second.

Answer (score 0):

Look at when you start your timers:  You give each SeparateExecution object one second to count as high as it is able, but one second starting from when?

Your first object's one second includes the time needed to create all four of the SeparateExecution objects plus the time it takes to create all four threads, plus the time it takes for its own thread to start up.  Your last object's one second includes the time it takes to create one SeparateExecution instance, plus the time it takes to create four thread objects, plus the time taken by three start() calls, plus its own thread startup time.  That's a significant handicap.

---

Edit:  Here's my version.  It does one measurement using a local counter, it does another using an instance variable counter, and then it launches threads (I get eight threads on my PC) that do the instance-var test concurrently.  When I run it, the first two runs count to roughly the same number which is around 1.5 x higher than the counts produced by the concurrent runs.

```
public class Threadly {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        doLocalVar();
        doInMainThread();
        doMultiThreaded();
    }

    private static void doLocalVar() {
        long count = 0L;
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long endTime = startTime;
        while (endTime - startTime < 1000L) {
            count += 1L;
            endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
        System.out.println("local: elapsed=" + (endTime - startTime) + ", count=" + count);
    }

    private static void doInMainThread() {
        Spinner spinner = new Spinner("main");
        spinner.run();
        spinner.show();
    }

    private static void doMultiThreaded() throws InterruptedException {
        int numThreads = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        Thread[] threads = new Thread[numThreads];
        Spinner[] spinners = new Spinner[numThreads];
        for (int i=0 ; i<numThreads ; i++) {
            spinners[i] = new Spinner("t-" + Integer.toString(i));
            threads[i] = new Thread(spinners[i]);
        }
        for (Thread thread : threads)
            thread.start();
        for (Thread thread : threads)
            thread.join();
        for (Spinner spinner : spinners)
            spinner.show();
    }

    private static class Spinner implements Runnable {
        private long startTime;
        private long endTime;
        private long count;
        private final String name;

        Spinner(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        // @Override
        public void run() {
            count = 0L;
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            endTime = startTime;
            while (endTime - startTime < 1000L) {
                count += 1L;
                endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
        }

        void show() {
            System.out.println(name + ": elapsed=" + (endTime - startTime) + ", count=" + count);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree with you and have made the changes to reflect your suggestion.  However the effects are negligible with the sum of all four threads(57924881) now only slightly greater than the single loop(53024376). I am expecting somewhere near 4x the performance.

Comment: @QuickPrototype in that case, you should be looking into SamDufel's question:  How many cores are available to run your program?  What value is returned by Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(); ?

Comment: I get a value of 4 from Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()

Comment: @QuickPrototype One other thought, and then I am out of ideas:  Your single-threaded loop increments a local variable, but your threaded loops increment an instance variable.  I don't know enough about Java bytecodes and the JVM to know whether that could account for the difference.

Comment: @james The kernel call of `currentTimeMillis` is "synchronized", that's all there is to it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the kernel for system time only responds to a single call and queues the others. E.g. if it has a synchronized call somewhere. Since its performance is the limiting factor, you are measuring how many times you can call System.currenttime(), which is roughly the same in both cases. The remaining difference is down to context switching and general overhead of maintaining threads.

Try making a for look inside the while loop, so it only checks the time condition once every thousand additions or so. This should be enough to make System.current time no longer the limiting factor.

Comment: Interesting suggestion: I tried wrapping the computation of runtime calculation like such:`if (value%10000 == 0) {runtime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start_time;}` this generated the following output: Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() : 4
71800000
DEBUG-> Time should be 1sec : 1001
worker1 DONE 19890000 Thread Exection Time 1001
worker2 DONE 24930000 Thread Exection Time 1001
worker4 DONE 22000000 Thread Exection Time 1001
worker3 DONE 22470000 Thread Exection Time 1001